# Why bufio.Scanner does not offer HasNext() func?

Tags: go

Why [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) does not offer `HasNext()` function?

Is there any alternative way to do so?

Comment: How is HasNext different from the existing [Scan](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner.Scan) method?  What is the problem you are trying to solve with HasNext?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Check it but not read it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why bufio.Scanner does not have a HasNext method is a question for the standard library designers.

Here's how to wrap a Scanner with HasNext functionality:

```
type ScannerPlus struct {
    bufio.Scanner
    scan  bool   
    valid bool 
}

func (s *ScannerPlus) Scan() bool {
    if s.valid {
        s.valid = false
        return s.scan
    }
    return s.Scanner.Scan()
}

func (s *ScannerPlus) HasNext() bool {
    if !s.valid {
        s.valid = true
        s.scan = s.Scanner.Scan()
    }
    return s.scan
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because [`bufio.Scanner`](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#Scanner) is only to read, not to check if there is more to read.

> Successive calls to the `Scan` method will step through the 'tokens' of a file, skipping the bytes between the tokens.
> The specification of a token is defined by a `split` function of type `SplitFunc`; the default split function breaks the input into lines with line termination stripped

So Scanner itself has no notion of "next". A split function helps define that and then `scanner.Scan() bool` can tell, based on the split function, if there is more.